# Ordering Branches in Graph with nx

Tags: python, networkx

Is there a way to create a graph with an ordered branch constraint ?

For eg. If I have a parent-child relation: 
Following is the python nx snippet for it.

```
 >>> import networkx as nx
 >>> g = nx.DiGraph()
 >>> nodelist = ['A','B','C','D']
 >>> for each in nodelist:
 ...     g.add_node(each)
 ... 
 >>> g.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','D'),('C','D')])
 >>> import nxpd 
 >>> nxpd.draw(g)
 '/tmp/nx_xdDmyn.png'
```

This is the output:

[image: NX OUTPUT]

Even upon changing the orders in the nodelist and add_edges_from list, the output doesnot seem to get affected.

But I am to get the output on which ever node is encountered first.

For instance: Suppose the nodelist were,

```
['A','C','B','D']
```

then the output should've been as shown below.

```
      A
    /   \
   B     C
    \   /
      D
```

How to achieve this using python networkx ?

Comment: Is your goal to create a graphviz drawing?  There is no guaranteed ordering of nodes and edges with the networkx DiGraph class (other than the edge tuples have the specified orientation of source-target).

Comment: Yes. precisely, I am to plot the graph using graphviz/pydot.